# v-if not working without v-else using computed property that returns Vuex state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am not sure where the problem is, however, basic `v-if` is just not working properly.

```
<template>
   <div>
       <select v-model="col.code">
            <option v-for="i in foo" :value="i.code">{{ i.code }}</option>
       </select>

       {{ col }}
       // { "code": "B" }

       <div v-if="col.code"> // not working
            {{ col.code }}
       </div>
   </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    data() {
       return {
           foo: [
            {code: 'A'},
            {code: 'B'},
            {code: 'C'}
           ]
       } 
    },
    created() {
        this.view();
    },
    watch: {
        '$route': 'view',
    },
    computed: {
        col() {
            return this.$store.state.col;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

However, if i add `v-else`, result will be rendered.

I also found out, that if i am doing same thing, without computed property, but with data property directly, it is not working either. What makes it to work is to add  around v-if statements.

```
<div>

    <select v-model="col.code">
        <option v-for="i in [1,2,3,4,5]" :value="i">{{ i }}</option>
    </select>

    <div v-if="col.code">
        {{ col }}
    </div>

</div>
```

Strange.

Comment: what's the action used to update the `col` state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that's no problem with `<div v-if="col.code">` but binding the select to a computed property is wrong, so you should use a computed setter :

```
  computed: {
        col: {
            get(){
              return this.$store.state.col;
             
              },
            set(newVal){
              this.$store.commit('UPDATE_COL',newVal); 
            }  
        }
    }
```

```js
Vue.use(Vuex)
//store instance
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    col: {
      code: 'A'
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    UPDATE_COL(state, payload) {
      state.col = payload
    }
  }
})

//vue instance
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data() {
    return {
      foo: [{
          code: 'A'
        },
        {
          code: 'B'
        },
        {
          code: 'C'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  created() {

  },

  computed: {
    col: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.col;

      },
      set(newVal) {
        this.$store.commit('UPDATE_COL', newVal);
      }
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="col.code">
    <option v-for="i in foo" :value="i.code">{{ i.code }}</option>
  </select>


  <div v-if="col.code">
   My code : {{ col.code }}
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Its not working either. No errors, nothing. col => get works, however col => set, does not. I also tested without computed property, with basic data proeprty. Its not working also.

Comment: please share your store and if you could share some codepen code it would be very helpful

Comment: Its very basic. Almost the same, as you posted. Just router is included and mixins. Anyway... i know that your answer is probably correct, however, its just strange that i need to wrapp v-if arround another root element.

Comment: the issue could come from the store state

Comment: Even without store state, with basic data, its also not working. Anyway, i found a workaround. I know that your code works, because i used it before. Thanks

Comment: if the state is initialized like `state: {
    col: {
     
    }
  },` could raise an issue